# Excel formula for tracking tasks and workload on two tabs

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

[image]

I created a spreadsheet at work to track all of the classes taught for us during the year. It helps us with scheduling and it helps us plan our budget for part time instructor payments. We have full time folks included too and we use it to make sure that they have met their contract load. An basic version of what it would look like can be seen above.

I would like to add a tab that grabs the course data from the first worksheet/tab and tallies it by faculty member name in the second tab (like what you can see below). Is there a formula for something like that?

[image]

Can it grab their names and total their workload (credits, enrollment and payment) by term and then total it for the year?
I tried to search your forum but, I wasn't sure how to refer to the function/operation that I am looking for. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you post a link to the image you want to embed above (on DropBox or something), I will edit it in for you.

Comment: like this? courses_tab_001.png (file://SEPO-AIMEEB/Users/0367270/Dropbox/courses_tab_001.png)

Comment: In this image I manually retrieved and calculated what I would like to automate faculty_tab.png (file://SEPO-AIMEEB/Users/0367270/Dropbox/faculty_tab.png)

Comment: These links are seem to be invalid. For information on how to share DropBox links, look here https://www.dropbox.com/help/167/en.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1cxj764uhscg6h/courses_tab_001.png

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2pa5vove8mnl2m/faculty_tab.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is called a **crosstab**, which is short for "cross tabulation", and in MSExcel-land, the term for that is a [**pivot table**](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=intro+to+pivot+tables+in+excel).

Comment: This seems much more likely. Thank you I'll give it a shot